# onmousewheel, on window or document?

Tags: javascript

I am experimenting with scroll events and in a few scripts that I have looked at I found this line:

```
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = somefunc;
```

This is working as intended, the somefunc is triggered on scroll. My problem is that Chrome is triggering the function twice (obviously because Chrome is responding to both the window and the document event). I would like to know why both events are used, is it due to cross browser compatibility? If so, which browser prefer which event? I would like to choose only one of the events, but I don't know which.

Comment: You should always use window

Comment: show the somefunc code, there might be some problem. nothing wrong with window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel

Comment: why is it so popular to use document then?

Answer (score 0):

if you have frames in your html, they are not included in the document, and thus the mouse wheel event won't be triggered.